# Is it possible to filter AWS S3 objects based on certain metadata entry?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, boto3

I am using Python 3.6 and boto3 library to work with some objects in s3 bucket. I have created some S3 objects with metadata entries. For example,

```
bucketName = 'Boto3'
objectKey = 'HelloBoto.txt'
metadataDic = {'MetadataCreator':"Ehxn"}
```

Now I am wondering if it is possible to filter and get only those objects which have a certain metadata entry, for example,

```
for obj in s3Resource.Bucket(bucketName).objects.filter(Metadata="Ehsan ul haq"):
    print('{0}'.format(obj.key))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The `list_objects()` command does not accept a filter.

You would need to call [`head_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.head_object) to obtain the metadata for each individual object.

Alternatively, you could activate [Amazon S3 Inventory - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily listing of all objects with metadata.